# No puedo actualizar un campo en mi base de datos MySql desde Java

Tags: java, mysql

Hola estoy teniendo un problema al momento de actualizar un campo en mi base de datos, no me arroja ningun error solo no actualiza el campo en la base de datos.

Tengo la Clase Producto y un constructor que es el siguiente:

```
public Producto(String strNombreProd, double fltPrecio, double fltPrecioMayor, int intCantidad, String strUbicacion) {
    this.strNombreProd = strNombreProd;
    this.fltPrecio = fltPrecio;
    this.fltPrecioMayor = fltPrecioMayor;
    this.intCantidad = intCantidad;
    this.strUbicacion = strUbicacion;
}
```

Y en mi interfaz tengo un evento que al momento de hacer clic sobre un icono puedo cambiar el nombre de dicho producto:

```
private void btnActualizaNombreMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                                
    try {
        String nombre = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese el nuevo nombre de:\n" + txtNombre.getText());
        txtNombre.setText(nombre);
        producto = new Producto(txtNombre.getText(), Double.parseDouble(txtPrecio.getText()), Double.parseDouble(txtPrecioM.getText()), Integer.parseInt(txtCantidad.getText()), txtUbicacion.getText());
        material.UpdateProducto(producto);
        updateTabla();
    } catch (NullPointerException | NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Y lo olvidaba este es el método donde me conecto a la base de datos:

```
public void UpdateProducto(Producto producto){
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/empresa", "root", "pass");
        String Sentencia = "UPDATE producto SET Nombre_Producto = ?,Precio = ?, Precio_Mayor = ?, Cantidad = ?, Ubicacion = ? WHERE Nombre_Producto = ?";
        ps = con.prepareStatement(Sentencia);
        ps.setString(1, producto.getStrNombreProd());
        ps.setDouble(2, producto.getFltPrecio());
        ps.setDouble(3, producto.getFltPrecioMayor());
        ps.setInt(4, producto.getIntCantidad());
        ps.setString(5, producto.getStrUbicacion());
        ps.setString(6, producto.getStrNombreProd());
        ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            ps.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DATMaterial.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**Solo tengo el error al actualizar el campo de nombre_producto pero cuando actualizo otros campos, los actualiza sin problemas**

Comment: Podrías agregar el "CREATE" de la tabla? O cuales restricciones tiene, etc. Estas trabajando con Hibernate o algo similar?

Comment: @FedericoMadoery no estoy trabajando con hibernate ni ningún otro framework  y este es el script de la tabla

`CREATE TABLE producto(
Nombre_Producto VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
Codigo VARCHAR (13) PRIMARY KEY,
Precio DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL,
Stock BOOLEAN DEFAULT true,
Precio_Mayor DECIMAL(6,2),
id_ubicacion VARCHAR(10),
Cantidad INT(7),
Cantidad_Minima INT (3),
Empresa VARCHAR(15),
Imagen_Codigo BLOB
);`

Comment: Nota aparte: evitar usar variables globales para la conexión y el prepared statement. No hay ninguna ventaja a hacerlo en tu código, y es peligroso.

Comment: En cuanto a tu pregunta, no me parece que simplemente es un problema con tus parámetros y tus datos, no con el código. ¿Has probado ejecutando el SQL directamente en la base de datos?

Comment: Si y no he tenido ningún problema cuando ejecuto la sentencia en MySQL y gracias por el consejo

Comment: A ver, si dices que actualiza los demás campos, pero el nombre del producto no, lo primero que deberías verificar es si efectivamente el método de la clase `Producto` te está devolviendo algún dato realmente... me refiero al método `getStrNombreProd`, que usas, aquí: `ps.setString(1, producto.getStrNombreProd());` aunque es extraño que el campo a modificar sea parte del `WHERE` al mismo tiempo... Otra cosa que podría estar ocurriendo es que la actualización viole alguna regla de integridad. Yo probaría con un nombre de producto escrito a mano, y muy raro, para ir depurando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como dicen la respuesta anterior no deberias usar un campo que no sea la primary key para realizar una actualización a un registro especifico, por otro lado cuando modificas el nombre no te actualiza porque el nuevo nombre no está en la tabla aun: Piensa en esto:

Quieres cambiar el nombre de **producto 1** a **producto 2** entonces el query que tu haces tiene en la clausula where `... WHERE Nombre_Producto = 'producto 2'` por obvias razones no va a encontrar nada que actualizar.

Te recomiendo dos cosas:

1. Agrega al método que guarda la siguiente modificación:

`int cantRegActualizados = ps.executeUpdate();
    if(cantRegActualizados == 0) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "alert",String.format( "No se ha actualizado el producto. El producto %s no existe",producto.getStrNombreProd()), JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }`

Si le pones un poco de logica al mensaje te daras cuenta del error de inmediato.

2. Que uses el debug parar ver los datos que le estas enviando al query y asi poder encontrar este tipo de errores, si no sabes hacer debug aca te dejo un buen link [Como hacer debug en netbeans](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5USkL8aDKeA)

Comment: Gracias lo logré solucionar cambiando el `where` ahora le asigné codigo como parametro para que actualice el campo.
Muchas Gracias

Comment: Es con mucho gusto Roberth, no olvides votar por la pregunta es un buen gesto :)

Answer (score 1):

Debes usar tu `priary_key` en la clausula `WHERE` según lo que me indicas en tu `CREATE` es 'Codigo', no el nombre del producto.
**No es recomendable** utilizar campos que no sean la primary_key para referenciar consultas, si estas pueden modificar dichos campos.

Cambia tu sentencia por esta:

```
 String Sentencia = "UPDATE producto SET Nombre_Producto = ?,Precio = ?, Precio_Mayor = ?, Cantidad = ?, Ubicacion = ? WHERE Codigo  = ?";
```

Luego cambia el string que seteas en dicha posición:

```
public void UpdateProducto(Producto producto){
    try { 
         //... tu codigo
        ps.setString(6, producto.getCodigoProd());
        ps.executeUpdate();
         //.. resto del codigo
```

Comment: Ya lo intenté pero sigo sin poder actualizar el campo nombre_producto, con los demás no tengo ningun problema

Comment: Acabo de ver, que has dicho que te funciono.

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez porque estas usando Nombre_Producto como si fuera tu clave primaria. Mejor  agregar un id_producto(valor único)...

"UPDATE producto SET Nombre_Producto = ?,Precio = ?, Precio_Mayor = ?, Cantidad = ?, Ubicacion = ? WHERE **id_producto** = ?";

vuelve a intentar

Comment: De hecho mi clave primaria se llama codigo, además cuando actualizo otros campos se actualiza sin problemas.